# Get information whether a surface is visible from a point light source or not

Tags: mesh, uv, light, faces, visibility

I am working on an optimization problem where I want to find information about the amount of faces of a mesh visible from a set of randomly distributed points. Ideally, I would like to index the faces `{1,2,...,N}` and calculate a visibility index for each face stating whether each surface is visible from each individual point or not. It is also important that the evaluation is quite fast (less than a second). I am hoping to find a solution to this problem using Blender.

A simple example of the output I want:

[image: Example face visibility list.]

In an early attempt, I have used the Suzanne mesh and a point light source in Blender Render. I UV-unwrapped the mesh using the Lightmap Pack and baked a lightmap. To get a distinct difference between visible and shadowed faces I did the following modifications of the the lamp:

- Energy increased from 1 to 1000
- Ray Shadow enabled
- Light falloff disabled (no distance attenuation)

Left: Test scene with Suzanne mesh and point lamp. Right: Baked lightmap where visible faces are white, hidden faces are black.

[image: Test scene overview.]
[image: Test scene baked lightmap.]

However, this method does not give me the visibility of each face in a direct manner. Instead, I would have to postprocess the lightmap image to extract the information I want.

Any ideas how I can achieve what I am trying do?

Thanks in advance!